# What does the recursive argument mean in dir.create?

Tags: r, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to get my head around the *dir.create()* function to create nested folders "folder2" and "folder3".

The solution would be:

```
dir.create(file.path("folder2", "folder3"), recursive = TRUE)
```

**Edit:** explanation of `?dir.create` is

> ****recursive***  logical. Should elements of the path other than the last be created? If true, like the Unix command mkdir -p.*

What is the purpose of the *recursive* attribute?

Comment: There is no 'threads' concept on StackOverflow. Every post solves only one specific problem, so creating a new post for your question is the right way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Picking up from 'mkdir -p' in your question, and explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089586/what-does-the-mkdir-p-mean-in-a-script-file#:%7E:text=mkdir%20%2Dp%20means%3A%20create%20the,to%20be%20adapted%20as%20required.):

If your 'folder2' included parent folders, these will need to be created first, else the create function would not be able to create the final file at the end of the path (there wouldn't be anywhere to put it, as the full path doesn't exist yet).

Lets say 'folder2' was 'a/b/c/'. To create folder 'c', you first need to create folder 'b'. But for 'b' you first need 'a'. So all the *parent* folders need to be created before the final *child* folder (or file).

'recursion' refers to 'stepwise repeating again and again'. [make 'a' then 'b' and finally 'c']

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a `Temp` folder in your working directory. If you want to create a folder within a folder in `Temp`.

```
dir.create('Temp/A/B/')
```

This will fail since folder `A` is not present. However,

```
dir.create('Temp/A/B/', recursive = TRUE)
```

will work and create a folder `B` within folder `A`.

Comment: Thats makes it clear to me. However it also raises one thought: Why is the recursive option at all changeable to FLASE. But maybe I will get to this once I am more familiar with R.